# Two devise models, two application controllers, one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I am running into a problem where I have two separate devise models (Admin and User), and because I am using a multi tenancy gem called Milia I need to two application controllers (One for the Admin which is outside of the tenancy and one for the User which is inside the tenancy. The problem is I need to access one controller from both of those devise models, but I can only inherit that controller from one of the below application controllers. Is there a way around this where I can specify which user should use which application controller when hitting the controller for a particular resource? Or is there another way around this problem?

The two application controllers look like this

```
class AdminApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_action :authenticate_admin!
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_action :authenticate_tenant!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Give you some inspiration :)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_them

  def authenticate_them
    authenticate_tenant!
  end

end

class AdminApplicationController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_them

  def authenticate_them
    authenticate_admin!
  end
end

class AnotherController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_them
  def authenticate_them
    if admin_signed_in? or tenant_signed_in?
       #or whatever other authentication you want
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think only the top-level ApplicationController needs the  `before_action`. The other controllers will inherit that.

Comment: actually, @CraigBuchek sub-classes are inheriting and overriding the method, so better call their own method.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a good reason to have some duplication of the `before_action` line — clarity.